# How to pass and set the slider image display time in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, slider, jquery-slider

I've used one image slider. The HTML and jQuery code for it is as follows :

**HTML code :**

```
<div class="leaderboard">
  <ul id="demo1">
    <li><a href="#slide1"><img src="img/Slid1.png" alt="Lorem Ipsum"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide2"><img src="img/Slid2.png"  alt="Lorem Ipsum"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide3"><img src="img/slid3.png" alt="Lorem Ipsum"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery code :**

```
$(function() {
  var demo1 = $("#demo1").slippry({
    transition: 'fade',
    useCSS: true,
    speed: 1000,
    pause: 3000,
    auto: true,
    preload: 'visible'
  });
  $('.stop').click(function () {
    demo1.stopAuto();
  });
  $('.start').click(function () {
    demo1.startAuto();
  });
  $('.prev').click(function () {
    demo1.goToPrevSlide();
    return false;
  });
  $('.next').click(function () {
    demo1.goToNextSlide();
    return false;
  });
  $('.reset').click(function () {
    demo1.destroySlider();
    return false;
  });
  $('.reload').click(function () {
    demo1.reloadSlider();
    return false;
  });
  $('.init').click(function () {
    demo1 = $("#demo1").slippry();
    return false;
  });
});
```

The necessary jQuery and CSS files have been already included.

This image slider is working perfect for me. But now I want to set some value in seconds (say for example 5 seconds. This is a variable value, it can be other than 5 seconds too.) for which each image from this slider appears. In other words I want to display each image for 5 seconds, as soon as 5 seconds are completed the next image should come.

How should I pass this value of 5 seconds to the above jQuery slider function and use this value into a function such that each image from slider will appear for 5 seconds?

Thanks for spending some of your valuable time in understanding my issue. If you need any more information regarding this issue please let me know.

Any kind of hep would be highly appreciated. Waiting for your precious replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the slide to last 5s change the value

```
var demo1 = $("#demo1").slippry({
    transition: 'fade',
    useCSS: true,
    speed: 1000,
    pause: 5000,// changed from 3000(3s) 
    auto: true,
    preload: 'visible'
});
```

you can get more information here http://slippry.com/settings/

**Edit 2**

you will need to do something like this

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/auqmv3qn/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But still my question is not answered. How should I pass this time to the slider function? As I said it's a variable so it needs to be passed to the slider function. Can you help me in this? It will be really very useful for me.

Comment: i didn't understand you want to increase the time right? so you need to change the pause time in your jquery code to pause: 5000

Comment: Yes, you got my point but what I'm saying is I shopuld be able to set this time dynamically by passing the time as a function argument. How should I do this?

Comment: i have edited my answer you will need to do something like that